# Reverse animation for NavigationLink?

Tags: swift, animation, swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink

I am currently trying to implement a back button in my app.  I have some Views linked through NavigationLinks and I'm using the default animation.  I am pretty sure the default is .easeIn but tbh I can't really tell the difference between them.  I tried making it .easeOut bc I assumed it would go the opposite way but it doesn't.  I want my back button to essentially have the reverse direction of the normal animation to move forward in the app, but I can't seem to find a good answer in the documentation.  Is there a good way to just reverse the default animation so it looks like it's going backwards?

Comment: If you use `NavigationLink` you have the back button automatically, with back animation. So I don't really understand your question.

Comment: I hid the navigation bar because it was compressing my page, and created my own back button.  I want it to mimic that functionality.

Comment: please share your code

Comment: NavigationLink(destination: Home()) {
                        Image("BackArrow")
                            .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 50, alignment: .leading)
                            .padding(.bottom, 75)
                    }
                    .animation(.easeOut)

Comment: and at the bottom of the view I have .navigationTitle("")
            .navigationBarHidden(true)
            .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)

Comment: ...you should put the code in your question, in a way that somebody else can test it: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: i don't feel like the code is even relevant for my question as it's pretty simple.  i simply am asking if I am able to replicate the animation that the back button for a NavigationView does, on my own button that I created.

Comment: but this is how it works here. this time you're lucky, @HunterLion just gave you the answer.

Answer (score 2):

I have mimicked the `NavigationLink` behaviour in one of my apps, because I needed more control on the behaviours and UI elements.

Basically, I have given a transition to the `List` view and an opposite transition to the detail view. If you add some "chevron" system images and place the buttons in the right position, a good eye can catch the trick, but I think it works pretty good for the average user.

Here is the code, check out the `.transition()` in each view (just remember to use `withAnimation()` when changing the state):

```
struct Example: View {
    @State private var detail: String? = nil
    
    let details = ["First", "Second", "Third"]
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            
            if detail == nil {
                List(details, id: \.self) { item in
                    Text("Tap to see the detail \(item)")
                        .onTapGesture {
                            withAnimation {
                                self.detail = item
                            }
                        }
                }
                .transition(.asymmetric(insertion: .move(edge: .leading), removal: .move(edge: .trailing)))
            } else {
                VStack {
                    Button {
                        withAnimation {
                            detail = nil
                        }
                    } label: {
                        Text("Back")
                    }
                    Text("Now you see only \(detail ?? "not found")")
                        .padding()
                }
                .transition(.asymmetric(insertion: .move(edge: .trailing), removal: .move(edge: .leading)))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you not need the onTapGesture for the back button? I tried implementing just the else clause since i only need the back functionality, and it didn't do anything.

Comment: Being a `Button`, it will automatically be tappable. The trick of the code above is that there is a `@State` variable (detail) the will will trigger either one or the other view. With `NavigationLink`, this trigger is provided by the system, that's why the "Back" button alone will not work - at least not using the approach presented in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

For the back button you can use this with a reverse animation:

```
@Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode

var body: some View {
   Button {
     presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()                     
   } label: {                 
     Image("BackButton")                     
   }                  
}
```